# Xamarin requires a Mac to compile, but are there remote Mac services out there so I don't need one?

Tags: xamarin

I've been wanting to try out Xamarin for a long time but, from what I understand, you need a Mac to compile on. So, in layman's terms, it's kind of like CoffeeScript or TypeScript, in that it compiles to actual intended target language's output and to do this it still needs the Mac. If that's how it is then I completely understand.

My question is, are there services that would basically act like my own Mac, but over the internet? Can I just pay somebody for their Mac build server, per month, and connect Xamarin to it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A Xamarin.iOS Build Host can pair with only one instance of Visual Studio. Hence, I cannot figure out a solution that you are looking for.

Comment: Your statement is inaccurate and it does not provide a solution and should not be the answer to this question.

Answer (score 9):

This

http://www.macincloud.com/

might be solution for you, but I did not test it and there are few references about feasibility of this approach and alternatives. MacInCloud has Xamarin Studio on their list and support for public static IP addresses.

Some Xamarin forums discussion about this idea (Mac environment and requirements):

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8345/is-there-a-way-to-build-in-the-cloud

There is more info in the forums, but not much more...

Comment: You can connect Visual Studio 2015 directly to macincloud Mac for Xamarin.iOS remote build (need the remote build addon). You can also use their VSTS plan to do CI and CD using Xamarin and Visual Studio Team Services.

Answer (score 1):

The latest builds (not sure if stable channel yet) have a completely reworked build host that only uses tcp port 22 (like ssh) so should be very easy to use a remote build host, open up firewalls safely etc see

https://blog.xamarin.com/introducing-our-first-release-candidate/

Note this also allows you to connect multiple visual studio instances to one build host

Comment: Yes, but how do you get debugging on an iOS device to work?

Comment: Suspect you can't not with debugging in he normal sense, that's why things like Xamarin Test Cloud exist, real, remote on device resting

Answer (score 1):

Note http://macstadium.com is another service offering remote build for Xamarin environments.  Enjoy...

Answer (score 0):

To add onto @moljac and the mention of macincloud, VS comes with a built in iOS emulator once you have paired with your mac device for the remote builder. You can use this emulator to debug, troubleshoot, test, etc.

Visual Studio has come a long way with Xamarin and Mac integration since this question was originally posted.