# Do I need to be connected to a mac, to be able to develop IOS-apps in VS on Windows?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.mac

I'm new to cross-platform mobile development with Visual Studio, and I'm wondering if it's possible to make IOS apps without connecting VS to an active mac. Seems a bit weird to always have a mac at your disposal, up and running to be able to develop IOS apps. Or maybe that's just how it works. Problem is I don't have a mac.

Is there another way?

Comment: Have been answered almost a thousand time, not only for Xamarin. Apple sets such a restriction and interestingly everyone wants to break.

Comment: @LexLi I personally think it is quite normal to want to get around rules that provide no value other than to consolidate control and restrict access. At least I have never heard of a reasonable argument for how this rule provides value to developers.

Comment: @hvaughan3, the value does not go to the developer,  Apple allows you to program for their device completely free via XCode, so to make their money back on this, they need to restrict access to Apple devices.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Apple makes money by charging $99 for the apple developer program. Forcing developers to buy apple hardware should not also be an added cost of developing an iOS app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin requires a Mac to compile, but are there remote Mac services out there so I don't need one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877457/xamarin-requires-a-mac-to-compile-but-are-there-remote-mac-services-out-there-s)

Comment: @hvaughan3 the $99 covers the cost of hosting your app on there servers among other costs.  You do not need the developer licence anymore to be a hobbyist

Comment: @Knight0fDragon So why would I need to pay more money than the cost of hosting the app on their servers? One of the primary points of making iOS apps is not to just create it, run it in debug mode on your own device and then be done. It is to distribute it to others for them to enjoy as well. If all you want to do is run the app on your device, then it should be completely free. That still does not justify forcing you to buy a Mac.

Comment: Why should it be completely free?  Who are you to say what apple does with its products.  They let you develop for free, XCode does not have multiple versions that have cost tiers, plus with Xamaran they would lose out on that money if they did go that route, so smart on their part.  There are a lot of costs involved with hosting and licensing your app,  remember the people that actually make sure your app works need to get paid as well, and at $99 a year that is a steal.  You could do the $25 for life on android, but then you deal with a market flooded with inferior untested apps.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon The fact is that when us developers make awesome apps, we drive users (AKA $$$) to apple or to what ever platform the app is made for. That is one of the reasons Windows Phone is doing so poorly, they do not have good apps. So Apple is already making money when developers make cool apps and our $99 is a drop in the bucket compared to the number of users that Apple gets because of the amazing apps in the App Store. They are double dipping by forcing you to buy their hardware, buy their apple dev program membership, and making money from the users our apps attract.

Comment: They are def not double dipping,  the $99 is the up front cost for a developer to weed out the bad apps and ensure quality apps are put out.  There is no guarantee though that this app will be successful, and of the billion apps out there, less than 1% are.  Apple needs to recover this loss some how,  why should those successful have to pay for it.  Bottom line. Its apples decision, not yours,  do not like it, do not develop for them,  make your own device or switch to windows phone or android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is indeed how it works. You can thank Apple for that. They require iOS apps to be built on Apple hardware.

Many people will use mac providers such as [Mac In The Cloud](http://www.macincloud.com/). If you Google services such as that you will find a long list of them.

There is also some hacks you can use to get a Mac running in VMware which have worked for me but that is not suggested as it violates terms of service for Apple and also probably for VMware.

Comment: does it runs well enough in VMware? isn´t so slow? i'm thinking in buy a gaming laptop instead an overpriced mac

Comment: It worked fine for me but that was a while ago. You could probably try out VMWare's trial and use the hack script to give it a try.